# Can Biztalk flat file schema check the record count in footer compared with actual record count?

Tags: biztalk

We have a CSV flat file like the following:

```
aaa,bbb,ccc  
ddd,eee,fff  
ggg,hhh,iii  
~~~0003
```

"~~~0003" is the footer, which mean there are 3 records in the file.

Is it possible to have a flat file schema in BizTalk such that the count can be compared with the actual number of records such that the validation is failed using flat file disassembler pipeline, if the number of records in footer does not match?

Answer (score 1):

No.

You would either

1. Have write a custom flat-file disassembler pipeline component (possibly extending the standard one)
2. Have a map which maps the a document which has both the footer count, and a count of the actual rows.  Then depending if it is a messaging only or if you are using an Orchestration either

   a. Make both those counts a promoted property and have a routing rule for when they are equal and another for when they are not.

   b. Have them as a distinguished property and a decision shape in the Orchestration that compares the two values.

Option 2. being the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking specifically is not possible.

It's fairly easy to check though, but you'll have to use an Orchestration.

On the Message with BTS.LastInterchangeMessage == true, check BTS.InterchangeSequenceNumber against the value in the footer.